# strncpy taking a long time

Tags: c++, strncpy

I have recently encountered some legacy code and noticed that sometimes (not always) the following code snippet takes a very long time to execute.

```
#define NUM_OF_RECORDS 100000
char* pzBuffer = new char[NUM_OF_RECORDS + 1];
strncpy(pzBuffer, "", NUM_OF_RECORDS);
```

The objective seems to be to initialize the pzBuffer and I agree that memcpy or memset would be a better choice. I'm trying to figure out why it's taking time and if the usage here is correct.

Comment: did you profile it in order to be sure that these are slow commands?

Comment: Why are yoiu not using `std::string`?

Comment: I used gstack to check and also put debug log lines just before and after the above code to verify. I can simply use std::string but I don't understand why this takes such a long time.

Comment: @user3265139 How long does it take exactly?

Comment: between 1 and 2 minutes on a linux back-end

Comment: What, between 1 and 2 minutes? Most likely you are running debug build. Even though `strncpy` fills remaining buffer content with zeros, filling 100 kb with zeroes takes no time. http://ideone.com/J2Jgmg

Comment: @Rabbid76 But the source string is empty. It only needs to compare once, and then fill the rest of the buffer with zero.

Answer (score 0):

using `memset()` could do better due to the following reason:

1)`strncpy()` works at individual 'char' level meaning it would iterate over all chars one by one (`~NUM_OF_RECORDS` iterations in your case).

2)`memset()` works at block level where a block consists of say N bytes. Although this means going over individual bytes of a block, this function is designed for optimizations w.r.t. large block sizes, which often result in better performance when blocks of large sizes are involved.

I would recommend creating variants of your code 1)using memset 2)other with strncpy. Then, compile both of them to generate assembly code, and find out the difference between instructions.

Answer (score -2):

http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/BSD4.4Lite/newsrc/libkern/strncpy.c.html

loks like the standard implementation of strncpy fills all remaining elements of the array with zeros, no matter what. So, it takes time doing that,.

```
    do {
        if ((*d++ = *s++) == 0) {
            /* NUL pad the remaining n-1 bytes */
            while (--n != 0)
                *d++ = 0;
            break;
        }
    } while (--n != 0);
```

Comment: Have you actually measured how long this code takes to run on your machine for an array like in OPs question?!

Comment: BSD 4.4 Lite is not "the standard implementation" (and AFAICT its last release was in 1995). glibc uses `memset` rather than a loop, as does Darwin.

Comment: Well, the initial question was about why the strncpy took so long. Presumably a similar implementation was used there. One should check.